# Code coloring for js and jsx not working is Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

I have provided the image above. Today, I open my visual studio code and I was not able to see proper colors for the code(only  for .jsx and .js files). The color of the code for .css file is as it was earlier but the whole code of the other files is white in color.

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted the language extensions for js(x).

Go to the Marketplace or use the integrated Extensions view and check if it is deleted.

Comment: No, it is installed